# Stop vuforia image tracking on hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

I'm working on hololens 2 project with inage tracking.
2019LTS unity
Vuforia 9.8
MRTK 2.6.0

Flollowing the tutorial：
[Working with the HoloLens Sample in Unity](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Working-with-the-HoloLens-sample-in-Unity.html)
And start an empty project.

I found the object can't autoly disappear when I move the image out of vision.
I use the default setting and test it on my andriod device. It always works just as what I want.
I read the other any similar question but seems out of time. And I never meet this problem in andriod-vuforia development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't have a clear description of your problem. I think you should at least attach the relevant screenshots.

But I can probably guess what your problem is. This is an update of vufaria 9.

In vufora 8, you may need some works with the code, now you just need to check:
[track target status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO2xN.png)

hope that could help you.